# Google rejecting android build for non-existent Request_Install_Packages permission

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play-console

I have an Ionic framework Android app that used a plugin(file opener 2) that included the Request_Install_Packages permission in the manifest file for our app builds. First I manually removed the permission post ionic syncronization, google rejected the release for the same reason. The permission did not show in the google play console list of permissions for this build.

[app permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohy9y.png)

Second I completely replaced the file opener plugin with a plugin that doesn't request this permission at all. I submitted again and was rejected again. Does anyone have a suggestion because google is giving zero information on the rejections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have other distribution tracks such as internal test, closed test or open test? If yes, try to update the versions of all tracks, I was having this problem too and it was resolved after removing this permission on all tracks.

Comment: This is exactly what was happening with our app. We had deactivated tracks in Closed testing with old versions of our app. Google was denying the prod release of the app without letting us know that our test track versions were the reason. 

It's criminal they don't give you the proper information upon rejection to find this out on your own. I had to appeal a rejection to find out their true reason for rejection.

Answer (score 0):

they fixed it here:
https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/issues/329

if it still happens, so search for this permission at your plugin folder to see which plugin uses it.